# rails:assets:precompile adds the proper tailwind classes but calling bin/dev (rails tailwindcss:watch) doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css

I'm not sure what the issue is but I'd love to understand what I'm doing wrong.
Whenever I need to add a new class I'm expecting `bin/dev` to be able to load and add the classes ie: `w-20` however, it doesn't and right now the only thing I'm able to get working is calling `rails:assets:precompile`.

I'm using `gem "tailwindcss-rails"` and it has been working before. I'm not getting any errors when starting. Here's my `config/tailwind.config.js`

```
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  content: [
    "./app/helpers/**/*.rb",
    "./app/javascript/**/*.js",
    "./app/views/**/*",
    "./app/components/**/*",
    "./app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Inter var", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
    require("@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio"),
    require("@tailwindcss/typography"),
    require("daisyui"),
  ],
  daisyui: {
    styled: true,
    themes: true,
    base: true,
    utils: true,
    logs: true,
    rtl: false,
    prefix: "",
    darkTheme: "dark",
  },
};
```

my Procfile for `bin/dev` is

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch
js: yarn build --watch
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.profile-name {
  @apply mb-4 text-4xl;
}
h1 {
  @apply mb-3 text-3xl;
}
h2 {
  @apply mb-3 text-2xl;
}
h3 {
  @apply mb-3 text-xl;
}

th {
  @apply px-6 py-4 text-gray-900 border;
}
table {
  @apply min-w-full p-4 text-center border;
}
tr {
  @apply px-4;
}
td {
  @apply p-1 text-gray-900 border whitespace-nowrap;
}
form {
  @apply mb-5;
}
ul li {
  @apply list-disc list-inside;
}
ol li {
  @apply list-decimal list-inside;
}
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS (and SCSS, if configured) file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

manifest.js

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../builds
```

I'm not sure what else to link, but thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What are in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css` and `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` files?

Comment: And what is in your `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file?

Comment: Just added above as well

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can try to add these two lines `//= link_tree ../../javascript .js`
`//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js` to your manifest.js file to make it work.

Comment: I added it, but no change was made.

Comment: Can you try one more thing?
Wrap your css classes in `@layer components { }`
For instance:
@layer components {
  .profile-name {
    @apply mb-4 text-4xl;
  }
}

Comment: Also no luck. The thing is, is that when I run `rails assets:precompile` it works just fine so something has gotta give around there. All the css shows up, including the thing I just  added (unlike `bin/dev`) but only when I run that command.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue in the past and  `rails assets:clobber` worked for me.

Comment: This will clean assets properly but it's not very developer friendly. You can't quickly change classes on html and see changes immediately as you would do on Tailwind 2.1 with JIT in just beta.

Comment: This also was the fix for me - running this once then made tailwind properly regnerate, thanks so much! saved me from running precompile then bin/dev each time i changed a class!

Comment: When and where should I place that command?  Thanks.